# I want to find max and min values in java

Tags: java

I want max and min values of salary to display but i get same values for max and min. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Wage {

String employee_name, skill;
int hours;
double sum;
String[] sno = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

public void getEmployeeDetails() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Use General Wage Record System");
    for (String count : sno) {

        if (count.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            System.out.print("Enter Name of Employee 1:  ");
            employee_name = s.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the Skill Level (1,2,3) of Employee:");
            Integer level_count = Integer.valueOf(s.nextLine());
            if (level_count <= 3) {
                System.out.print("Enter the Worked  Hours for  " + employee_name + ":");
                hours = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                if (level_count == 1) {
                    sum = hours * 15;
                }
                if (level_count == 2) {
                    sum = hours * 17;
                }
                if (level_count == 3) {
                    sum = hours * 21;
                }

                System.out.println("The wage of employee" + employee_name + "(Level" + String.valueOf(level_count) + ")" + "for" + hours + " " + "hours is" + " " + "$" + sum);
            }

        }

        if (count.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
            System.out.print("Enter Name of Employee 2:");
            employee_name = s.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter the Skill Level (1,2,3) of Employee:");

               Integer level_count = Integer.valueOf(s.nextLine());
            if (level_count <= 3) {
                System.out.print("Enter the Worked  Hours for  " + employee_name + ":");
                hours = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                if (level_count == 1) {
                    sum = hours * 15;
                }
                if (level_count == 2) {
                    sum = hours * 17;
                }
                if (level_count == 3) {
                    sum = hours * 21;
                }
                System.out.println("The wage of employee " + employee_name + "(Level " + String.valueOf(level_count) + ")" + "for" + hours + " " + "hours is" + " " + "$" + sum);
            }

        }

        if (count.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
            System.out.print("Enter Name of Employee 3:");
            employee_name = s.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the Skill Level (1,2,3) of Employee:");
            Integer level_count = Integer.valueOf(s.nextLine());
            if (level_count <= 3) {
                System.out.print("Enter the Worked  Hours for  " + employee_name + ":");
                hours = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                if (level_count == 1) {
                    sum = hours * 15;
                }
                if (level_count == 2) {
                    sum = hours * 17;
                }
                if (level_count == 3) {
                    sum = hours * 21;
                }

                System.out.println("The wage of employee" + employee_name + "(Level" + String.valueOf(level_count) + ")" + "for" + hours + " " + "hours is" + " $" + sum);
            }

        }

        if (count.equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
            System.out.print("Enter Name of Employee 4:");
            employee_name = s.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the Skill Level (1,2,3) of Employee:");

              Integer level_count = Integer.valueOf(s.nextLine());
            if (level_count <= 3) {
                System.out.print("Enter the Worked  Hours for  " + employee_name + ":");
                hours = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                if (level_count == 1) {
                    sum = hours * 15;
                }
                if (level_count == 2) {
                    sum = hours * 17;
                }
                if (level_count == 3) {
                    sum = hours * 21;
                }
                System.out.println("The wage of employee" + employee_name + "(Level" + String.valueOf(level_count) + ")" + "for" + hours + " " + "hours is" + "$ " + sum);
            }

        }
    }

}

void average() {
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    System.out.println("stastical information for bar chart");
    System.out.println("==================================");

    if (sum > max) {

        max = sum;

        System.out.println("Maximum of wage" + max + ",  " + employee_name);
    }
    if (sum < min) {
        min= sum ;
        System.out.println("Minimum of Wage" + min + ",  " + employee_name);
    }
}

}

 public class Pay {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Wage wm = new Wage();
    wm.getEmployeeDetails();
    wm.average();
}
```

Comment: You only call `average()` once, so only one value of `sum` is considered, i.e. the last assigned value, so `min = max = sum`.

Comment: how to call can u please ellaborate with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop of the `getEmployeeDetails()` method, you don't store and update the min wage, the max wage and the employee names that have these wages.
Besides, you should be more specific in the naming. For example, `maxWage` and `minWage` are more meaningful than `max` and `min`.
So, you should have `maxWage`, `maxWageEmployeeName`, `minWage` and `minWageEmployeeName` fields  in the field declaration of the `Wage` class.

At each employee inserted in the system, you should update these values by calling a dedicated method:

```
public void getEmployeeDetails() {

  if (count.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
    ....
    updateRanking(sum, employee_name);
  }
}

public void updateRanking(double actualWage, String employee_name){
    if (actualWage > maxWage) {
        maxWage = actualWage;
        maxWageEmployeeName = employee_name;
    }
    else if (actualWage < minWage) {
        minWage = actualWage;
        minWageEmployeeName = employee_name;
    }
}
```

Besides, your `average()` method called at the end of your program should only display the result and not performing comparison since you should have updated information about max, min wage and who have these as `updateRanking()` is called at each insertion of employee wage :

```
void average() {
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    System.out.println("stastical information for bar chart");
    System.out.println("==================================");           
    System.out.println("Maximum of wage" + maxWage + ",  " + maxWageEmployeeName );      
    System.out.println("Minimum of Wage" + minWage + ",  " + minWageEmployeeName );       
}
```

Comment: whaat about average

Comment: Add a `double totalWage` field in the class  initialized to `0`and  in `updateRanking()` method, increment to this actualWage. Then in the  `average()` method, you get the wage average by dividing `totalWage` by the number of inserted employees